# muti-dimentional java arraylists for machine initializing

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I am looking for a type of mutidimensional-arraylist which can be initialize by an array just like regular 2d arrays. Such as this:

```
for(int o = 0; o < n; o++) {
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        num[o][i] = sc.nextInt();
    }
}
```

I greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: It's not in std library, you should try by yourself and paste code here if you get an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple 2d array could be initialized with the help of `Arrays.fill(primitive[], primitive)`, just like this:

```
final int[][] arr = new int[10][10];

for (int[] brr : arr) {
        Arrays.fill(brr, 0);
}
```

It would generate you a 10x10 arrays with lots of zeros for you.

I found this guy here [ND4J](https://deeplearning4j.org/docs/latest/nd4j-overview), it resembles a lot Numpy. I believe it could be useful to you too. It has a [zeros method](https://deeplearning4j.org/docs/latest/nd4j-overview#createzero) too =)

Comment: sorry, what I was looking for was this page. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642205/java-arraylist-of-arrays