# Will be Array of ArrayList or Double dimension array be the better data structure for this java translation program

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm writing some research Java code to manipulate with the strings and stuck,
need some help with ideas and proper data structure and algorithm for the problem below.
I have created some simplified version of the problem as separate java class in the code below.

Need to translate input string **s_in**
letter by letter to return **String[] array R** with
all possible translations.

Each letter could be translated by **translate_letter()**,
which takes letter in, and output String[] array out.
The complexity is, that size of out array could be 
anything from 1 to 4.

I have created initial information gathering and data structure
as arrays, list of arrays and double dimension array.

Couldn't proceed any further, because cannot come up with idea,
how to actually produce final output **array R[]** - 
need a data structure and algorithm to process translation
dynamically regardless of quantity of letters in input string
(it will be anything from 1 to 10 in practice).

Test cases:

```
1) If s_in = "a"
R[] will be just R[] = { "a1" }

2) If s_in = "ab"
R[] = { "a1b1", "a1b2" }

3) If s_in = "abc"
R[] = { "a1b1c1", "a1b1c2", "a1b1c3", "a1b2c1", "a1b2c2", "a1b2c3" }

4) If s_in = "db"
R[] = { "d1b1", "d2b1", "d3b1", "d4b1" }
```

This is my final version of the code:

```
import java.util.*;


public class translate_string {


//------------------------------------------------------------
/*

This is simplified version to set-up proper data structure
and algorythm.

Need to translate input string s_in
letter by letter to return String[] array R with
all possible translations.

*/

public static void main (String args[]) throws Exception {

    // input string to translate
    String s_in = "a" + "b"; // 

    // split String s_in into String[] array of each letter
    String[] lt = s_in.split("");

    // len of lt array (how many letters)
    int lt_len = lt.length;

    // array - how many combo for each letter
    int lt_cmb[] = new int[lt_len];

    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642205/java-arraylist-of-arrays
    //Declaration of an ArrayList of String Arrays
    ArrayList<String[]> lofAL = new ArrayList<String[]>();

    // storage for temp array of returned translations
    String[] array;

    // total qty of combo from s_in: N = lt_cmb[0]*lt_cmb[1]*lt_cmb[2]...
    int N = 1;

    // max length of returned translations
    int max = 0;

    int i = 0; // loop vars
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < lt_len; i++ )   { // for i

        // lt[0] = a  lt[1] = b  - each letter from ori s_in
        // ori lt[] array of letters

        // in array of String[] - all combo for letter lt[i]
        array = translate_letter(lt[i]);

        // add each array as next element of ArrayList lofAL
        lofAL.add(array);

        // add len of each array (letters) into lt_cmb
        lt_cmb[i] = array.length;

        if ( lt_cmb[i] > max ) { max = lt_cmb[i]; }

        // multiply total qty of combo
        N = N * lt_cmb[i];

        System.out.println("lt[" + i + "]=" + lt[i] + " lt_cmb[" + i + "]=" + lt_cmb[i]);


    } // end for i

    System.out.println("N=" + N + " lt_len=" + lt_len + " lofAL.size()=" + lofAL.size() + " max=" + max);

    // lt_len must be = lofAL.size()

    // 2-dim matrix array of letters
    String[][] F = new String[lofAL.size()][max];
    for (i = 0; i < lofAL.size(); i++ ) {
        for (j = 0; j < max; j++ ) {
            F[i][j] = ""; // ini 
        }
    }

    // final ready array R
    String[] R = new String[N];
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {
        R[i] = "";
    }   


    int count = 0;

    for( i = 0; i < lofAL.size(); i++ ) { // for i 2

        count = 0;

        for( j = 0; j < lofAL.get(i).length; j++ ) {

            F[i][j] = F[i][j] + lofAL.get(i)[j];


/*
            if ( count == 0 ) {

                R[i] = R[i] + lofAL.get(i)[j];
                k = k + 1;
                count = 1;

            }

            if ( count == 1 ) {

                R[i] = R[i] + lofAL.get(i)[j];
                count = 2;

            }
*/


            // Printing out the ArrayList Contents of String Arrays
            // '$' is used to indicate the String elements of String Arrays
            System.out.printf(" $ " + lofAL.get(i)[j]);

        }

        System.out.println("---------------");

    } // end for i 2


    for ( i = 0; i < lt_len; i++ ) { // for i3

        for ( j = 0; j < max; j++ ) {

            System.out.println("F[" + i + "][" + j + "]=" + F[i][j]);

        }

    } // end for i3


    for ( k = 0; k < N; k++ ) { // for k

        j = 0;

        for ( i = 0; i < lt_len; i++ ) { // for i

            if ( lt_cmb[0] == 1 ) { j = 0; }

            R[k] = R[k] + F[i][j];

        } // end for i

    } // end for k



    System.out.println("================");

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {

        System.out.println("R[" + i + "]=" + R[i]);
    }   



} // end main()
//------------------------------------------------------------
// translate letters - return array of diff combinations
public static String[] translate_letter(String s) {

ArrayList<String> o = new ArrayList<>(1);

if ( s.equals("a") ) { // if a 
    o.add("a1");
} else {

if ( s.equals("b") ) { // if b
    o.add("b1"); o.add("b2");
} else {

if ( s.equals("c") ) { // if c 
    o.add("c1"); o.add("c2"); o.add("c3");
} else {

if ( s.equals("d") ) { // if d 
    o.add("d1"); o.add("d2"); o.add("d3"); o.add("d4");
} else {

    o.add(s); // s = def add (if nothing above matches)

} // end if d 

} // end if c

} // end if b

} // end if a

//Convert ArrayList o to string array[]
String[] array = o.toArray(new String[o.size()]);

return array;

} // end translate_letter()
//------------------------------------------------------------


} // end class()
//---------------------------------
```

Comment: Is your code working? Is it doing what you want it to? Do you have an exception and a stack trace? If so, please edit your question to show this.

Comment: Don't mix lists and arrays. You can just use `String#toCharArray()` to get a `char[]` of the characters. In general, prefer lists as easier to work with. After that... it's really unclear what the spec on this problem is, but it seems like a `Map<String, List<String>>` might be the most suitable. `LinkedHashMap` if insertion order is important.

Comment: Code is compiling and working. But it is not doing what expected.
There are no exceptions. Simply - the main part - creation of output is not done and this is nature of the problem.
Spec of the problem is simple: I have string as input, need to translate string, have a function of translation of each letter , but cannot translate the whole string, because some letters could give more than one variant of translation. Don't go into details of Chars vs String - I will be working with the strings anyway.